# An integral representation of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

I am referring to the equality in equation $3.29$ (page 12) and $4.20$ (page 17) in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6290v2.pdf).

I am unable to recognize where this comes from or what is the general expression for values other than $3$.

I checked at some online reviews like this - http://www.math.utah.edu/~milicic/zeta.pdf but nothing seems to match.

It would be great if someone can help.

---

<sub>(Images added by J.O'Rourke)</sub>

   [image: 3.29]

 [image: 4.20]

Comment: Where did you come across this?

Comment: Use the integral representations of $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$ for $s=3$.

Comment: The equation is incorrect as stated; you want $\zeta$, not $\xi$.  But be that as it may, asking *us* where it comes from without telling us what you already know is a really good way to get your question closed.

Comment: "I came across" is a poor introduction. _Where_ did you see this? Context? Of course some (possibly corrected) version can be adduced from known things, etc., but ...

Comment: I have now added a reference to the kind of formula I am looking for.

Comment: Why not actually put the equation here in the post? Asking people to go dig through a linked PDF is perhaps asking too much.

Comment: Which one of the three equal signs in (3.29) do you want to see explained? The rightmost one follows from the series expansion of the denominator in terms of $\mathrm e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\lambda}}$ and a term-by-term integration. The same approach probably also applies to the rightmost equal sign of (4.20).

Answer (score 3):

you ask for the "general expression" for values other than $q=3$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}d\lambda\frac{\lambda^{q/2-1}}{1+e^{2 \pi  \sqrt{\lambda}}}=2^{1-2q}(2^q-2)\pi^{-q}\Gamma(q) \zeta(q),\text{ for Re }q>0$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}d\lambda\frac{\lambda^{q-1}{\rm coth}(\pi\lambda)}{1+e^{2 \pi  \lambda}}=(2\pi)^{-q}\Gamma(q) \zeta(q),\text{ for Re }q>1$$

Comment: Can you give a reference to its derivation? I hope there is a way to relate these identities to other better known representations?

Comment: http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta/07/01/

Comment: Thats just a list of formulas :( Isn't there any first principles way of getting these identities? Like from the power-series definition itself? It looks like an impossible task to just know or even guess these identities when they come up in a calculation! [...i wonder how the authors of this paper saw this while doing this!..]